# Creating object with foreign key in it

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

whenever I try to run "add_rat" in the below code I get the error

```
    Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "441": "Myrating.movieId" must be a "Movie" instance.
```

I tried passing it as movieId_id=movieId in the function definition bu that gives the error:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I also tried passing it as int() value but it did not work.

I want to create Myrating object which has 2 foreign keys.

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Movie,Myrating
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import csv


# Register your models here.
def add_set(modeladmin, request,queryset):
    with open('./movies.csv','r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as _filehandler:
        csv_file_reader=csv.DictReader(_filehandler)
        for row in csv_file_reader:
            movie=Movie.objects.create_movie(row['movieId'],row['title'],row['genres'],"mov.jpg")
add_set.short_description = "New_Day"
def add_rat(modeladmin, request,queryset):
    with open('./ratings.csv','r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as _filehandler:
        csv_file_reader=csv.DictReader(_filehandler)
        for row in csv_file_reader:
            movie=Myrating.objects.create_movie(int(row['userId']),Movie.objects.get(movieId=row['movieId']),float(row['rating']))
add_rat.short_description = "New_rat"
def add_user(modeladmin,request,queryset):
    i=1
    while i<=7045:
        user = User.objects.create_user(i, '', 'password')
        user.save()
        i+=1
add_user.short_description = "New_use"
class movie_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('title','genre')
    list_filter=('genre','title')
    actions=[add_set,add_user,add_rat]
admin.site.register(Movie,movie_admin)
admin.site.register(Myrating)
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db import models
class movie_manager(models.Manager):
    def create_movie(self, movieId,title,genre,movie_logo):
        movie = self.create(movieId=movieId,title=title,genre=genre,movie_logo=movie_logo)
        # do something with the book
        return movie
class Movie(models.Model):
    movieId=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    movie_logo  = models.FileField()
    objects=movie_manager()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
class rating_manager(models.Manager):
    def create_movie(self, user,movieId,rating):
        movie = self.create(user_id=user,movieId=movieId.id,rating=rating)
        # do something with the book

        return movie
class Myrating(models.Model):

    user    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movieId= models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating  = models.IntegerField(default=1,validators=[MaxValueValidator(5),MinValueValidator(0)])
    objects=rating_manager()
```

Comment: You should pass it as `movieId_id=movieId.id` But normally foreign keys, do not *have* an `Id` suffix (since now you got two `ids` for the "twin field").

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried that too, it is giving FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error

Answer (score 0):

You have movieID which is referenced to Movie model, for this when you save you need to provide the value which should be the instance of Movie.

`movie = self.create(user_id=user,movieId=movieId.id,rating=rating)`

here movieID is Movie instance but you assign movieID.id which is an int.
that's why it throw error.

`Cannot assign "441": "Myrating.movieId" must be a "Movie" instance.`

**Following are the solutions.**

`movie = self.create(user_id=user,movieId=movieId,rating=rating)`

or

`movie = self.create(user_id=user,movieId_id=movieId.id,rating=rating)`

You can rename Myrating **movieId** field to **movie**, because movie name is meaningful since it relate to Movie instance.

You can follow official documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/) for more details and examples.